# Groovy DSL: How I can overload any() in Groovy, when I create internal DSL

Tags: groovy, dsl

I create Internal DSL and I would overload any() method from DefaultGroovyMethods.

```
class RulesProcessor {

}

Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbours dies
```

The last line is my DSL. I tried propertyMissing, methodMissing, create my Any class, RulesProcessor.metaClass.any, DefaultGroovyMethods.metaClass.any, but they doesn't work.

How I can write code to accept my DSL? Only first step with 'Any' word is complicated for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you can put it in a closure, just delegate it to an object which responds to `any` method or, as in my example, `invokeMethod`:

```
class Dsl {
  def params = []
  def invokeMethod(String method, args) {
    params << [method, args]
    this
  }

  def propertyMissing(String prop) { prop }
}


a = {
  any live cell with fewer than two live neighbours dies
}


dsl = new Dsl()
a.delegate = dsl
a()

assert dsl.params == [
  ['any',   ['live']],
  ['cell',  ['with']],
  ['fewer', ['than']],
  ['two',   ['live']],
  ['neighbours', ['dies']],
]
```

If you are reading the script from a file, having a method explicitly called `any` seems necessary:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilerConfiguration

class Dsl {
  def params = []
  def invokeMethod(String method, args) {
    params << [method, args]
    this
  }

  def any(param) { invokeMethod('any', [param]) }

  def propertyMissing(String prop) { prop }
}

code = 'any live cell with fewer than two live neighbours dies'

parsed = new GroovyShell(
    getClass().classLoader, 
    new Binding(), 
    new CompilerConfiguration(scriptBaseClass : DelegatingScript.class.name)
).parse( code )

dsl = new Dsl()

parsed.setDelegate( dsl )
parsed.run()

assert dsl.params == [
  ['any',   ['live']],
  ['cell',  ['with']],
  ['fewer', ['than']],
  ['two',   ['live']],
  ['neighbours', ['dies']],
]
```

Kudos to [mrhaki](http://java.dzone.com/articles/groovy-goodness-set-delegating) on CompilerConfiguration.